# Terraform import Azure devops project

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

I was trying to import the existing Azure devops project to a terraform state file. While importing i'm looking to import all the features of the Project such as Repo, pipelines,artifact, policies, etc. I'm using the below code to perofrm the terraform import

```
terraform import azuredevops_project.project "MyAZDOProject"
```

But in the state file generated had only the below details

```
version": 4,
 "terraform_version": "1.0.6",
 "serial": 1,
 "lineage": "6424a0e7-fe60-2791-948a-e35af6248de2",
 "outputs": {},
 "resources": [
   {
     "mode": "managed",
     "type": "azuredevops_project",
     "name": "project",
     "provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/microsoft/azuredevops\"]",
     "instances": [
      {
      "schema_version": 0,
      "attributes": {
        "description": "",
        "features": {},
        "id": "fba9899a-4697-4813-8fed-51913462c1cc",
        "name": "MyAZDOProject",
        "process_template_id": "b8a3a935-7e91-48b8-a94c-606d37c3e9f2",
        "timeouts": {
          "create": null,
          "delete": null,
          "read": null,
          "update": null
        },
        "version_control": "Git",
        "visibility": "private",
        "work_item_template": "Basic"
      },
      "sensitive_attributes": [],
      "private": "eyJlMmJmYjczMC1lY2FhLTExZTYtOGY4OC0zNDM2M2JjN2M0YzAiOnsiY3JlYXRlIjo2MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAsImRlbGV0ZSI6NjAwMDAwMDAwMDAwLCJyZWFkIjozMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAsInVwZGF0ZSI6NjAwMDAwMDAwMDAwfSwic2NoZW1hX3ZlcnNpb24iOiIwIn0="
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

But i was expecting  it to import  all the AzDO features under the project "MyAZDOProject" in the tfstate file. What is the best way to import all the AzDO project detils like repo, pipeline, artifacts, permissions in the state file

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation some of your requirements (e.g. pipelines, artifact) doesn't support import or/and cannot be configured using provider microsoft/azuredevops with TF.

You are trying to import a project which looks correct. But azuredevops_project is a resource type defined in a provider and has limited count of attributes and covers only high level project configuration. Azure devops project consists of other pieces of resources which you can define in TF code or import to your state separately. Please look at documentation of microsoft/azuredevops provider to find the resources you need to import form your project:

- [Azure DevOps Project](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/resources/project)
- [Azure DevOps Teams](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/resources/team)
- [Azure DevOps Groups](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/resources/group)
- [Azure DevOps Git Repository](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/resources/git_repository)

But currently this provider looks outdated and does not support the new REST API functions that appeared after RestAPI version 5.1.

Additional Links:

- What are resources in TF: [Resources Overview](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources)
- microsoft/azuredevops provider documentation: [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs)
- [Microsoft RestAPI 7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)